# Prevent keyboard from popping up on EditText click?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

How do I prevent my keyboard to open when I'm selecting text from edit text? I want the text inside to be still selectable, while not opening the keyboard when I click it

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/displayalllinks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10" >
```

Comment: If you do not want the soft keyboard to appear, why are you using an `EditText`? Why not use a `TextView` with `android:textIsSelectable="true"`?

Comment: Why don't you want it to pop up? If you want it to go away after a button is clicked or something, try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1)

Comment: Your question is not clear, you should have either provided more details (e.g. not having to type in the View just selecting an already set text) or not using `EditText` at all.

Comment: My reason would be a calculator app that does not need the soft-keyboard but a custom layout with buttons. The reason for an EditText is because it can display a cursor so you can move it around and add digits between instead of removing all of the input first

Answer (score 3):

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_1);
boolean disabled = false;

//We listen for selection
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {

          //When selected, we disable input.
          if (editText.hasSelection()) {
              editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
              disabled = true;
          } else 
              //Then we restore it, if previously unset.
              if (disabled) {  
                  editText.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                  disabled = false;
              }  

        return false;
      }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by adding **inputType** of none and **textIsSelectable**:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/displayalllinks"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10" />
```

And

```
 EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_mine);
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imm != null  && editText.hasSelection()){
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }                
            return true;
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: This would disable the keyboard in all cases, not only when selected.

Comment: Oh ok, I updated my answer. please check if it's what you intended to do.

Answer (score 2):

It's a hacky behaviour, because as a user if you are clicking on an `EditText` you are expecting something to do with that text.

I've come up with this solution: extending `AppCompatEditText` and overriding `onTouchEvent()` behaviour.

```
public class MyEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int currentInputType = getInputType();
        setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        boolean b = super.onTouchEvent(event);
        setInputType(currentInputType);
        return b;
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Clicking on EditText doesn't open soft keyboard]

In this gif you see, that it doesn't break long click functionality.

Comment: But it doesn't prevent the keyboard from showing up

Comment: @Denny, the question was *"how to make keyboard **not** to show when `EditText` is clicked"*, it didn't tell anything about long click.